# Google Analytics. Where is historcal events data?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm receiving data from my GA, but it can be viewed only under the real-time reports events tab. But where GA stores these events? I mean where GA saves all received events? Is it possible to view for example events for several past days or several past months?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the sidebar choose "all events" and select the event you are looking for.
[image]

you change the time interval on the top left of the page.

[image]